# How to Debug when upstart hangs?

Tags: 12.04, server, upstart

I have recently much trouble with services started by upstart. Currently I have problems with avahi-daemon and rsyslogd. Most of the time i had that problem on Ubuntu >= 12.04.

**What's the problem?** If I stop such a service, the stop-script hangs (waited 2 day on one server). When I kill it the service remains in the following state `stop/killed, process <pid>` which is undocumented (just `stop/killed` is documented!). The service really is down.

Now when I try to start the service with `service <service> start` again the start script hangs, too.

My question to that is: How shall I **debug** such problems? The start/stop scripts just do nothing at a point and it is intranparent to me what causes this. I even had that problem with the *unattended-upgrades*

Answer (score 6):

The command to start system Upstart job is `sudo start <service>`. Since version 6.10. Upstart replaced the /sbin/init daemon handling starting and stopping tasks and services during boot/shutdown and supervising them while the system is running. [[1]](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Log files can be found in `/var/log/upstart/<service>.log`. You can increase log priority from the default *message* to *debug* to get more details. [[2]](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#initctl-log-priority)

Your problem is caused by wrong use of the expect fork stanza creating job with the status `job stop/killled, process nnn`. [[3]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/406397)

Comment: +1 for [3] and I was able to fix it with the script found at the bottom of the conversation there (talk about an extreme hack). https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/406397/comments/47